# Check all checkbox and store all selected items in a global variable

Tags: php, javascript, post, checkbox

I have a list of emails with a checkbox next to it, the user will be able to select which address he/she wants to email. Now i've added another checkbox that when checked will check all the other checkbox. Below is the code i wrote (with help from stackoverflow of course) :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function selectFunction (checkall,field)
{
    if(checkall.checked==true){
        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
            field[i].checked = true ;
    }else{
        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
            field[i].checked = false ;
    }
}

</script>

<form name="myform" action="profile-invite.html" method="post">
    <b>Your Favorite Scripts & Languages</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="1">aaa@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="2">bbb@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="3">ccc@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="4">ddd@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="5">eee@xxx.com<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="selectallcb" value="Check All"
    onClick="selectFunction(document.myform.selectallcb,document.myform.list)">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

The "select all" function works fine, but using print_r i saw that when the submit button is clicked, the submited value is the last checkbox that i selected. For example if i click 5-3-1-2, the value in $_POST is "2" and not the rest.

i realized that my code can only register ONE selected checkbox, therefore only the last one is taken into account. So I rewrote the code by adding [] behind the name of the checkbox :

```
<form name="myform" action="profile-invite.html" method="post">
    <b>Your Favorite Scripts & Languages</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="1">aaa@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="2">bbb@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="3">ccc@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="4">ddd@xxx.com<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="5">eee@xxx.com<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="selectallcb" value="Check All"
    onClick="selectFunction(document.myform.selectallcb,document.myform.list)">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Now, it registers the multiple selections when i checked with print_r.(if i click 5-3-1-2, the value in $_POST is now [0]=>5,[1]=>3,[2]=>1,[3]=>2.)

But the "select all" checkbox doesn't work anymore. I assume is due to the [] which transformed the field into an array. I tried various methods (by replacing "document.myform.list" with "document.myform.list[]" etc. ) None is working so far, i'll continue experimenting but if anybody have a clear idea on how to merge the 2 codes above please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
onClick="selectFunction(document.myform.selectallcb,document.myform.list)"
```

to this:

```
onClick="selectFunction(document.myform.selectallcb,document.myform['list[]'])"
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NxfH6/